# Spring batch job to update different tables

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am reading the article http://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/ which explains reading a csv and writing it back to a DB. I want to know how can I read mutiple CSV files say A.csv, B.csv etc and write the content back in respective tables table_A, table_B etc. Please note the content of each csv file should go in a different table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic use case here would be to create as much steps as you have CSV files (since there is no default `MultiResourceItemReader` implementation).

Each of your step would read a CSV (with a `FlatFileItemReader`) and write to your database (using `JdbcBatchItemWriter` or another one of the same kind). Although you will have multiple steps, if your CSV files have the same format (columns, separators), you can factorize the configuration using an `AbstractStep`. See documentation : http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html

If not, then you can at least share the common attributes such as `LineMapper`, `ItemPreparedStatementSetter` and `DataSource`.

---

**UPDATE**

Here are examples for your readers and writers :

```
    <bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="resource" value="yourFile.csv" />
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="names" value="column1,column2,column3..." />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                        <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="yourBeanClass" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="writer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql">
            <value>
                <![CDATA[        
                    insert into YOUR_TABLE(column1,column2,column3...) 
                    values (:beanField1, :beanField2, :beanField3...)
                ]]>
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Here's an example to chain the steps in the job (with Java-based configuration) :

```
@Bean
public Job job() {
     return jobBuilderFactory().get("job").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
     .start(step1()).next(step2()).build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean I create a `BatchConfiguration` class for every csv which has the reader and the writer for that csv. And how the job and the step will be defined in that case.. which file will they go

Comment: @dazzle I suggest you take a look at some tutorials as for how to create a Spring Batch job. You should also read the official documentation (starting here) : http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html.  I also put example of the readers and writer.

Comment: Thanks. I am clear about reader and writer as the link I pasted in my question shows how they are defined. My only question is (if you look at the BatchConfiguration.java in the link above) how would I define the new job with different steps (with each step being for each csv)

Comment: @dazzle Sorry I didn't read your question very thoroughly :D Since you're using the "java" way to create steps and jobs, I guess you'll simply have to create a different method for each of the steps (with their own configuration), and then a Job method which will create a chain between the steps. I updated the post again.

Comment: Thanks, will try this tomorrow.

Comment: its not allowing me to add `.end() ` before `build()`

Comment: @dazzle Yes, `.end()` is for flows, you don't need it with next, sorry!

Comment: Thanks. I have just posted my implementation in another question. Can you please help with that?